# Универсальная функция с 1 условием

Tags: python, функции, numpy

У меня есть какая-то обычная функция с 1 параметром:

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 42
```

Такую функцию я могу использовать как с простыми числами, так и с `numpy.array`, всё ок.

Но что если функция имеет 1 условие?

```
def bar(x):
    if x < 42:
        return x + 42
    else:
        return x - 42
```

В таком случае для `numpy.array` она уже работать не будет, а хотелось бы, чтобы ко всем элементам массива, которые меньше 42, прибавилось 42, от остальных -- отнялось.

Можно ли так написать функцию `bar`, чтобы она работала и с одиночными элементами, и с `numpy.array`?

Comment: Можно. Добавьте в функцию проверку передаваемого параметра и, на основании этой проверки выполняйте соответствующие действия.

Comment: @strawdog а без явной проверки типов никак?

Comment: @strawdog, а зачем проверка? Numpy функции умеют работать со скалярами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"В этой жизни можно все, молодой человек" — говорил мне преподаватель в универе. Особенно в Питоне. Главное понимать, что конкретно вы хотите. Конкретно по вашей задаче самым простым является проверка входящего типа. Мне, если честно, конструкции, которые принимают разные типы, и внутри их как-то кастят, не нравятся. Но вот как вариант:

```
def bar(x):
    if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x = np.array([x])
    cpy = np.array(x)
    for item in np.nditer(cpy, op_flags=['readwrite']):
        if item < 42:
            item += 42
        else:
            item -= 42
    return cpy
```

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю воспользоваться векторизированной условной функцией [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def foo(x, val=42):    
    return x + np.where(x < val, val, -val)
```

---

Тесты:

```
In [16]: foo(10)
Out[16]: 52

In [17]: foo(50)
Out[17]: 8

In [18]: foo(np.array([20, 40, 60, 80]))
Out[18]: array([62, 82, 18, 38])
```

Answer (score 1):

Может быть есть какой-то питонический способ, но мне сразу в голову приходит проверка типа входящих данных:

```
def bar(x):
    if type(x) == numpy.array: # не знаю как правильно определяется этот тип
        do something
    elif type(x) == int:
        if x < 42:
            return x + 42
        else:
            return x - 42
    else:
        do something different
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([100,1,45,13,65,0])
b = 13

def myfunc(p):
    if type(p) is np.ndarray:
        p[p<42]+=42
    else:
        p+=42
    return p
```

Проверяем:

```
print(myfunc(a))
print(myfunc(b))
```

Получаем:

```
[100  43  45  55  65  42]
55
```